# Restricting access of google app engine apps only to users in an organization

Tags: authentication, google-app-engine

I want to restrict the access of google app engine apps only to users in my organization. Also, I want them to be able to access these without connecting to the organization's VPN

I am using python 3.7 runtime and standard environment for apps deployed on app engine

[Using login: required handler is deprecated in python 3 runtime](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/migrate-to-python3/config-files#updating_appyaml)

```
handlers:
  login: required
```

Is there a similar and ready to use alternate to this?

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at Identity Aware Proxy. Visit [this](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/app-engine-quickstart) link for a quick tutorial.

- A benefit with IAP is that you don't need to make any changes to your application for it to work. All requests to your application will get authenticated with a google account and reach your code only if the user is logged in with a valid google account with **IAP-secured Web App User** role assigned.
- You can create a Google Group in your organization's G Suite which contains all  the users in the organization and assign the **IAP-secured Web App User** role to it. Then only users in your organization will be able to access the application.

Comment: There's one issue though- if a user has signed in with a non organizational account in the browser, if directly gives error 403: org_internal rather than asking to try a different account. Is there a way I can have an option for them to try with a different account? I am currently given IAP- secured web app user role to the domain 'org.com', where org is the organization for internal only access

Comment: the user will have to log out of their current google account and then access the application url. Then it will prompt to login again

Comment: Yup, exactly! It requires logging out of the current account. However, not a big trouble. Works fine, thank you

Comment: Please consider up voting or marking the answer as accepted if it helped.

Comment: I've already upvoted it. Maybe ders some minimum limit of upvotes required for it to appear here